# Adding a source in mapbox throws error "Input data given to 'some id' is not a valid GeoJSON object."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

```
map.addSource('some id', {
 type: 'geojson',
    data: {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {},
    "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
    -76.53063297271729,
     39.18174077994108
   ]
 }}]}});
```

The above code throws - **"Input data given to 'some id' is not a valid GeoJSON object."**
Anyone knows if I'm missing something here?

Comment: I figured it out, the source object had a maxClusterZoom property set to an invalid string Infinity